# Use keypass vault into jenkinsfile

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, vault

I have keypass vault credentials where I have stored the different credentials.
I need to integrate it into my jenkinsfile where I can use the credentials for performing different acitons. Can anybody help with some link or steps how can I integrate?
On searching I am getting mostly to use the credential manager available in jenkins.

I have tried exporting the kdbx file into xml and then using it but it will not solve the purpose and is not the recommended approach.

Answer (score 1):

As of now there is no plugin available for Jenkins to achieve this.

I've been using a workaround in Jenkins to call keepassxc-cli (command line tool which operates on the kdbx file) with master key/password stored in Jenkins's credentials manager and assign it to a variable in the pipeline. In addition to mask the sensitive data in logs the mask-passwords plugin can be used.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/mask-passwords/

But if you are using blue ocean, the data masked by this plugin is shown as plain text. It's a bug.